# POSTGRESQL array not always returning first NULL element

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a column in a table, with character varying[] type:

```
select details from x where id = 1;

Results:
[2:10]={wfeweqf,NULL,NULL,wefwf,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,wqfewef}
```

which means that detail[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlWjj.png) is null:

```
select details[1] from x where id = 1;
    
Results:
[null]
```

Is there a way to access all elements of this array, to get:

```
Results:
{NULL,wfeweqf,NULL,NULL,wefwf,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,wqfewef}
```

?

I guess is not the purpose of this mechanism of omitting first nulls in array, but unfortunetly I need whole array.

## edit:

---

### [image: details]

### [image: details1]

### [image: unnest]

[image: len]

Comment: Could you add the DDL and some example data to reproduce this? As well as the postgresql version you are using. I [can't reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5CfDAC3ir63GB51WUxnxxq/0) the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Is `x` a view? That's the only explanation I have that the result is only a slice of the original array.

Comment: I am not understanding your question. From what you show everything is working as it should. If you do `select details from x where id = 1;` you will get the complete array.

Comment: @Marth, @a_horse_with_no_name, @Adrian Klaver  Thank you for your answers. Honestly, I have a problem reproducing problem myself outside of a tabel, so I provided screenshots that I hope describe problem a bit more. I left FROM and WHERE outside of a screen because they are pretty descriptive for company, but this is simple a form of  `FROM table WHERE id = 1;`. I'm using pgAdmin 4. And no, `x` is not a view -  it is a table.